# How can I search description in Awesomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm using [Awesomplete plugin](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/).

```
<input class="awesomplete" list="mylist" />    
<datalist id="mylist">
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
      <option>Three</option>
    </datalist>
```

If I search `one/two/three` then it's working. But I want to add a description with each option.

Like this:

```
<datalist id="mylist">
  <option title="first">One</option>
  <option title="second">Two</option>
  <option title="third">Three</option>
</datalist>
```

And I want when I search `first/second/third` then will show the options `(One/two/three)`.
But I can't do this.

Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://projects.verou.me/awesomplete/prism/prism.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://projects.verou.me/awesomplete/awesomplete.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="https://projects.verou.me/awesomplete/awesomplete.js"></script>
<script src="https://projects.verou.me/awesomplete/index.js"></script>
<h1> Dropdown Search With Title </h1>
<input id="myinput" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById("myinput");
  // Show label but insert value into the input:
  new Awesomplete(input, {
    list: [{
        label: "One",
        value: "first"
      },
      {
        label: "Two",
        value: "second"
      },
      {
        label: "Three",
        value: "third"
      },

      {
        label: "First",
        value: "first"
      },
      {
        label: "Second",
        value: "second"
      },
      {
        label: "Third",
        value: "third"
      }
    ]
  });

  function myFunction() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("myinput").value);
  }
</script>
```

Explanation :-
You can map both labels with same value like the given example.
when user search/Select Third and Three then value will be the same.

this is how you can map this.

Comment: Hmmm. For that I've to use same codes many times. I don't want this. 
I want when I search Third then will show Three.

Comment: Look, If you want dynamic data. you need to map somewhere. without mapping, you can't be able to solve this issue.. hope this helps!